# Pandas DataFrame: Trouble Converting Column of Strings (?) to Int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm running some machine learning code that requires the values in my Pandas DataFrame to be numbers (floats, integers, etc.)  It looks like this (X is training set and Y is target vector):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X, Y)
views_predictions = lin_reg.predict(X)
lin_mse = mean_squared_error(Y, views_predictions)
lin_rmse = np.sqrt(lin_mse)
lin_rmse
```

However, I get this error when trying to run it:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: original
```

So, I check the dtype of my DataFrame and see that my `type` column is an object and not a string...

I tried this to remedy the situation:

```
final_df['type'] = (final_df['type'] == 'licensed').astype(int)
```

Unfortunately, I get a strange Type error:

```
TypeError: Could not compare ['licensed'] with block values
```

Not sure how to interpret this or remedy the problem.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't that error mean you tried to convert the string `"original"` to a float? Can we see your dataframe? I'm wondering if you have strings that can't be converted and thats causing the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your example makes it appear as if you are trying to convert actual words into integers, not just numbers stored as strings.

Usually to work with strings in sklearn models like this, you need to map your strings onto placeholder integer values. Try using a map like so:

```
type_map = {value: i for i,value in enumerate(list(final_df['type'].unique()))}

final_df['type_int'] = final_df['type'].map(value_map)
```

Now drop the original `final_df['type']` column and use the `final_df['type_int']` instead for your calculations.